# Restful Collections - how to either remove OR delete items

Tags: rest

I read quite some stuff about RESTful API Design. 
But when it comes to the implementation, it wasn't that easy anymore. 
I got stuck at the following problem:

Assume the following 2 endpoint:

1. /api/v1/users/:id
2. /api/v1/users/1/friends/:id

As we all can see, **friends is a collection** of the resource **user**.
A user can have n-friends in his friendslist (by standard this would be many to many, but for now, let's assume this to be one to many). 
Okay, now i want to **REMOVE** a user (*id=3*) from the friendslist of user 1 by doing the following HTTP-Request:

**DELETE api/v1/users/1/friends/3**

And this is where i got stuck - either the request **deletes** the whole user resource which has id = 3 or **removes** the resource from the collection. Because both would be valid Restful implementations i think.

So the question is:
**How to remove an item from the collection without deleting the original resource**

I hope that this question is no duplicate - but i did google a lot to find the answer. Maybe i don't know the related technical term to find some pleasing results...

Thanks in forward.

Comment: Why do you ask "How to remove"? If you ask "Should I use URIs like this tore remove an item from a collection without deleting the original resource?" I'd answer "Yes, that looks very RESTful". Is this your question?

Comment: Sorry i am a newbie at RESTful implementations - as i commented below, i always thought that DELETE on a Collection removes the link AND/OR deletes the original resource. So i was not sure how to implement DELETE on a collection. But like errata said, in the context of a collection, the DELETE-Method **just** removes the **link**. It does **not affect the original resource**. And that's the key! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach to REST looks fine but that really only speaks to path format and HTTP verb. The problem must be in your application code or app routes.

Comment: So to be clear: The DELETE-Method above should only remove the link to another resource from the collection. The linked resource itself will remain untouched. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. You should only be removing the friend relationship status, not user/1 or the user represented by /friends/3 but only the relationship between the two. If you had a users table and a friends table that had user_1 and user_2 field only the friends table should be affected.

Comment: I always thought that DELETE on a collection DELETES the linked resource too. That was my fault.... I thought too complicated about this... And now it's just one easy answer which made everything clear for me. Thank you so much! But just to complete this: To remove a linked resource itself, i would have to GET all friends which returns many links to user resources - and then call DELETE on one of that link which actually really points out to a specific resource. I think that's the right way. Many thanks dude!

Comment: that really comes down to application code and dependency. If the object is something that is OWNED by the parent resource then it makes sense to delete it, if it is a relationship then only the relationship should be destroyed in the sense that the rest endpoint represents a relationship and not the primary object it is pointing to, Again, any of this could be changed by the controller code. hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: So for example... employee : contactinformation = 1 : m. If i DELETE the employee, the contactinformation can also be deleted, because it depends upon the employee. Yes, that clears it up ;-) Many many thanks!

Comment: @errata Could you provide a link to a reference where the convention of DELETE-ing in the context of a collection simply removes the relationship? I like the approach you suggest but curious if its a "best practice" that you have come up with or if it is widely adopted or officially recommended

Answer (score -2):

I think it is better that DELETE api/v1/users/1/friends/3 would be used to delete user 3, just like DELETE api/v1/users/1 would be used to delete user 1.

To remove just user 3 from being a friend of user 1 I would use DELETE api/v1/users/1/friends and specify a filter to only remove friends with the id of 3.

DELETE api/v1/users/1/friends without a filter would remove all friends of user 1.

Likewise to add friends of user 1 I would use PUT api/v1/users/1/friends and specify the ids of the friends to add.

Comment: That just doesn't make sense... Why do your verbs applied to /friends deal with the friend relationship and not the actual users, but the verbs to /friends/3 deal with the user and not the friend relationship? It makes a whole lot more sense for DELETE  /friends/3 to delete the relationship between users (because that's what /friends represents) and not the actual user because you are accessing it under /friends not /users. If you want to delete a user, then DELETE should be applied to the actual user resource (/users/3)

Comment: That is what we would disagree about, and what this post asks about. Obviously we both agree that DELETE api/v1/users/1 would be used to delete user 1. As this post points out, friends can be thought of as a collection of users, in the same way that users can be thought of as a collection of users. If you use collection of users/3 then that would be referring to a user. In most of the APIs that I have worked with api/v1/users/1/friends/3 would refer to a user. I have also seen your way of thinking where friends refers to a collection of relationships, which also makes sense to some people.

Comment: api/v1/users/1/friends is a collection of users, but that collection is a relationship to api/v1/users/1, so when you delete anything from api/v1/users/1/friends, you are only deleting it from the api/v1/users/1/friends collection, not the api/v1/users collection. You are not deleting the root user from the entire API, because you aren't deleting a user from the api/users resource. The user will be gone from the api/v1/users/1/friends collection, but still exist in the api/v1/users collection

Comment: So in your way of thinking, DELETE api/v1/users/1 deletes a user, and DELETE api/v1/users/1/friends/3 removes a user from a collection. You are saying the same verb does 2 different things on a collection of users. I guess in your way of thinking if a user had addresses, then you would also need api/v1/addresses in order to be able to delete those addresses. As written before most APIs that I have worked with would disagree with you. Obviously some people would agree with you. I have seen many APIs all done differently. Please point to a RESTful specification where it says one way is right.

Comment: This isn't even slightly ambiguous. The _resource_ represented by /api/v1/users/1/friends/3 is the collection element. It is not the user referenced by that collection element. DELETE here removes the element from the collection. DELETE /api/v1/users/3 removes the element identified by 3 from the users collection. Semantically in your application that is the canonical collection of all users. Personally I use singular forms for the latter - eg /api/v1/user/1 and plural forms for _to-many_ entity relationships. But IMO ReST is a pretty cruddy idiom which I try to avoid.

Comment: Firstly I think you will agree that REST is not a standard which is why there are so many articles and books about this. Just google 'Best practices for REST API design' for example. You clearly disagree with most of the best practices I have read regarding plural verse singular, but that is not the topic of this POST. Many articles write about sub or nested resources, and that DELETE should delete the nested resource and not just remove it from a collection. Some try to avoid using nested resources for many to many relations for this exact reason. This is ambiguous hence Clemens question.